# Message passing from rabbitmq channel to java NIO channel

Tags: comet, rabbitmq, nio

I am building a chat component(where all discussions are saved) for an application and I planned to have a long-polling server as an interface between the client machines and the rabbitmq server, that will parse format and enqueue messages in a job queue(on rabbitmq) to be handled by celery, which will then check if posting is allowed via checking the db for some information, etc, save the messages to a db, and enqueue them in rabbitmq again, this time to be consumed by the long-polling server to be pushed out to the client machines.

I planned to have one connection from the rabbit server to the long-polling server, containing many channels, that will each correspond to a nio socket channel, where a client machine is listening in on the other end.

The long polling server will be written using the Java Nio libraries. My question is, what would be an efficient way of sending the messages from the AMQP channel to the socketchannel to be pushed out to the clients?

From my understanding of NIO, the only time a selectionkey should be registered for OP_WRITE, is when a previously attempted write() call returned 0. In this case though, I am interested in writing to a socketchannel when information is present on the corresponding AMQP channel. How can I alert the socket channel once data comes in on its corresponding amqp channel so that I may send data through the socketchannel to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call write()! No need to 'tell' the SocketChannel anything. Then if write() returns zero, do the OP_WRITE stuff.

Comment: Then I'd have to use another thread, subclass each of the amqp channels to contain a reference of all their corresponding socket channels and call write? Because the amqp channels are different objects than nio socket channels: http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v1.7.0/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-1.7.0/com/rabbitmq/client/impl/ChannelN.html

Comment: According to what I've read, you should only call write() after reading something from the socketrecv buf (i.e. having something to write). How would I even alert a socketchannel in the select loop in the event of data coming from an amqp channel?

Comment: just to be clear, the long-polling server will act as a consumer in this case, receiving messages from each amqp channel object which corresponds to a particular nio socketchannel where a user is sitting on the other end. In the select loop, the server acts as a producer, taking messages sent from users, format them properly and enqueues them in rabbit via an amqp socket.

Comment: @RoryBreaker You write when you have something to write, and when that is depends on your application protocol, not on the socket receive buffer. You don't have to 'alert the socket channel'.

Comment: Ok. If I have each of the amqp ch hold a reference to a nio socketchannel, I can simply attempt the write once the data comes in, and if it returns 0, just set the socketchannel for OP_WRITE and save the unfinished data in the attachment for the next select(). The socketchannel may be busy reading at the time the other thread calls write(), but a socketchannel supports concurrent reads and writes, correct? I've read that NIO has a bug that prevents concurrent reads and writes on a socket channel; is this still an issue(everything I've pulled up is pretty old)? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Read and write are concurrent, correct. The only bug I'm aware of  is that if you create streams for a SocketChannel via the methods of `Channels,` the input and output streams both synchronize on the same object so that `read` and `write` *via those streams* block each other.